# good idea or not good : to use coroutines for response Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

i want to ask a good developers. Maybe anyone can better explaine. Somewhere in web i found that few authors used coroutines instead for example asynctasks .  Just trying to improve myself . Here a small part of code which i used .  Just want to know - it's good or no. If no - how to make it's better or maybe in final im using this in wrong way.

```
 fun demoCall(callback: OnResponse) {
       CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
          val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
             Api.getResponse("GET", ApiConstants.test_endpoint)//networkOnMainThread exception if i will not use withContext
          }
          callback?.onResponse(result))
       }
  }
```

This example is work .  But im not sure it's good usage. 
If back to past ,

> getResponse

was in asyncTask. Call was same with annonymus callback. 
If to use this way is good , looks like i can use this part without callback ? 
Just like this

```
fun demoCall() {
 CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
       Api.getResponse("GET", ApiConstants.test_endpoint)
    }
    //do anything with result
    //populate views , make new response etc.. 
}
```

will be very happy if any tell me - is it ok or no :)  Regards

Comment: Well you definitely shouldn't be making a CoroutineScope per each request, you may as well use `GlobalScope` at that point.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  can you little more explaine about this  ? Please

Comment: If you want to have a good understanding of Kotlin Coroutines I greatly recommand you to start by exploring the [Coroutine Basics Guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html), this is the first step to understand when and how to use Kotlin Coroutines

Comment: @RobertLaFondue thank you buddy

Answer (score 1):

I prefer making asynchronous calls be seen like synchronous in caller's view using `suspend` keyword.

For example,

```
suspend fun demoCall(): String {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Api.getResponse("GET", ApiConstants.test_endpoint) // let's assume it would return string
    }
}
```

and caller can use it

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    val result = demoCall() //this is async task actually, but it seems like synchronous call here.
    //todo something with result
}
```